# How to separate string into shell arguments?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have this test variable in ZSH:

```
test_str='echo "a \" b c"'
```

I'd like to parse this into an array of two strings `("echo" "a \" b c")`.

i.e. Read `test_str` as the shell itself would and give me back an array of
arguments.

Please note that I'm not looking to split on white space or anything like that.  This is really about parsing arbitrarily complex strings into shell arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zsh has [`(z)` modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags):

```
ARGS=( ${(z)test_str} )
```

. But this will produce `echo` and `"a \" b c"`, it won’t unquote string. To unquote you have to use `Q` modifier:

```
ARGS=( ${(Q)${(z)test_str}} )
```

: results in having `echo` and `a " b c` in `$ARGS` array. Neither would execute code in `…` or `$(…)`, but `(z)` will split `$(false true)` into one argument.

that is to say:

```
% testfoo=${(z):-'blah $(false true)'}; echo $testfoo[2]
$(false true)
```

Comment: `(z)` was the key.  Thanks.  I also added an example of what I think you meant with your last point.

Comment: I'm curious why you decided to use `$(false true)` as an example? Is it a convention or arbitrary / for the lack of a better command?

Comment: This is one of the few commands which have no side effects (except for the return code which may alter execution flow) and do not produce anything regardless of arguments (`false` in zsh is silent even in case `false --help`, it will not produce help like `/bin/false --help` from binutils does). Not a convention I know about, but using `false` or `true` commands with any arguments is safe, with the addition that specifically `false` command may fail a script depending on settings (like `set -e`).

Answer (score 5):

A simpler (?) answer is hinted at by the wording of the question.  To set shell argument, use `set`:

```
#!/bin/sh

test_str='echo "a \" b"'
eval set $test_str
for i; do echo $i; done
```

This sets `$1` to `echo` and `$2` to `a " b`.  `eval` certainly has risks, but this is portable `sh`.  It does not assign to an array, of course, but you can use `$@` in the normal way.

Comment: Not sure if portable, but in bash, `eval set - $test_str` will prevent anything in $test_str being interpreted as the usual args to `set`